# Custom Maven Plugin: how to add classpaths?

Tags: java, maven, classpath, maven-plugin

I'm creating a custom plugin for maven. Normally, when you run a normal Java program that depends on some `.jar` files, you put it in the command line as a classpath. In my plugin, there are some things it needs to know about that are in other `.jar` files.

When compiling the plugin for maven, how do I add classpaths to my custom maven plugin? Would I add it as a dependency in the `pom.xml`?

Comment: Yes, it should be just that easy - everything you declare as dependency for the plugin ends up in its classpath when executed

Comment: @GyroGearless I must do something else wrong then, Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit and make clear why you need having dependencies during runtime instead of dependencies during build time?

Answer (score 0):

You can add things on the classpath of a plugin via defining dependencies for a plugin which works like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Apart from that it sounds strange that you need to define dependencies of a plugin during the runtime of the plugin.